# Grab Record ID before during submit and save to another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

Invoices & Invoices Parts

The reason i'm using two tables is because i dont want to save the invoice parts array into one record on the Invoices table and i dont want to save it into multiple records on the Invoices table.

When i submit the data into both tables, how can i link both tables together with the ID if i dont have the ID yet?

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO invoices(labelwarning, status, todaysdate, todaystime, todaysdatetime, avatar, firstname, lastname, mwaid, nextgenid, manager, manageremail, dispatcher, dispatcheremail, techemail, tag, serialnumber, currentequipment, company, address, city, state, zip, contactperson, contactnumber , currentdate, timearrived, timecompleted, login_id) VALUES('$labelwarning', '$status', '$todaysdate', '$todaystime', '$todaysdatetime',  '$avatar', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$mwaid', '$nextgenid', '$manager', '$manageremail', '$dispatcher', '$dispatcheremail', '$techemail', '$tag', '$serialnumber', '$currentequipment', '$company', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$contactperson', '$contactnumber ', '$currentdate', '$timearrived', '$loginId')");

$result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO invoiceparts(partnumber, partdescription, partprice, partquantity, partdb, login_id) VALUES '$partnumberstring', '$partdescriptionstring', '$partpricestring', '$partquantitystring', '$partdbstring', '$loginId')");
```

Comment: Have you tried http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to link the "login_id" and the login_id is generated with AUTO_INCREMENT then you can do it by

- for Mysqli connection,  mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
- for PDO connection, $mysqli->lastInsertId();

If the login_id is not an AUTO_INCREMENT field then you can do it by

- SELECT login_id FROM invoices ORDER BY login_id DESC LIMIT 1;

It'll return the last inserted row from there we can fetch the login_id